# How to skip tutorial?

Tags: simcity-2013

If you are like me, and having to switch to different servers so that you can play, then you're stuck having to watch the tutorial all the time.

How do you skip the tutorial?

Comment: closed, but my answer is better. Close the other one, and open mine. lol :)

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work that way. You can post your answer to the other question though

Answer (score 2):

To skip the tutorial.

Click the `Getting Started` button on the home screen. The tutorial city will load, and a welcome message popup will show in the lower corner.

You *must* click the `Okay` button to start the tutorial in order to skip it. If you don't start the tutorial, then it won't work.

Once the next popup appears called "CAMERA". Click the *options* button `(...` in the upper right corner, and then click `Exit To Main Menu`.

When you return to the main menu the tutorial will have been cancelled. You can now go and create your first city for that server.

Comment: Wooohoo - That worked. I thought i was stuck in an infinite loop. Thanks!